"Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDevAndroidDebugJavaWithJavac'" error
I'm getting this error when I try to run my flutter project:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDevAndroidDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-34 Android SDK Platform 34
      build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
  The SDK directory is not writable (/opt/android-sdk)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDevAndroidDebug failed with exit code 1

My OS is arch (btw) and I have ran

yes | sdkmanager --licenses

and

flutter doctor --android-licenses

This is the output of running flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Arch Linux 6.9.9-arch1-1, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/to/linux-android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

    ✗ No valid Android SDK platforms found in /opt/android-sdk/platforms. Directory was empty.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

I don't know why it isn't recognizing /opt/android-sdk as the sdk folder.
Also, if this helps with the issue, I have the following exports in my .zshrc file:
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/:$PATH


It seems that you need to append '/sdk' to the end of your export line then execute command source .bash_profile if there is a subdirectory named 'sdk' in /opt/android-sdk/.
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/sdk

I recommend you to install Android Studio to prepare for essential Android runtime environment.
